# Free alternative to Oracle Maestro PHP Generator

Tags: gratis, php, database

I need to create a PHP page, that allows me to create/edit database entries.

I have a table, with several entries, I need users to go on a web page, and then, see and edit entries, and this need to be sync with the database. If I change something on the PHP page, should modify the database too.

This is the main goal of : [Oracle Maestro PHP Generator](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/oracle/phpgenerator/)

I need features of the premium version (like inline edit with line displaying. In the free version, when you edit a line, that one becomes blank, and you cannot see how the line was...).

This is why I'm looking for a free alternative to this software.